# Does the dropper between the catenary wire and contact wire carry current?

Tags: three-phase, single-phase, voltage, jumper, contact

[image]

[image]

From my observations, droppers are of metal and they do not have any insulation from the catenary wire or from the contact wire.

The catenary and contact both carry the same phase and voltage so any voltage drop that occurs in the contact wire can be compensated through the catenary wire through droppers.

If droppers carry current then why do we need 'G-jumpers?'

Answer (score 3):

Trolley line maintainer here.

### Yes.

Because, trying to *insulate* the catenary wire from the contact wire would be sheer madness.  It's much easier to simply insulate the whole catenary-dropper-contact assembly from "the rest of the world".

Also, on lower voltage systems, line work is often done "live" (so that the line car is able to self-propel, as it is often an electric car *itself*. The workers on the roof platform are at the same voltage as the overhead line, so ground is lethal to them.  As such, we want *the entire workspace* at the same potential, including both wires and the cross-arms to the extent possible.

Now, your jumper in that photo appears to be linking *two* contact wires and *two* catenary wires.  That appears to be connecting two lines to each other.  This is common in actively tensioned lines with counterweights, where trolley segments are segmented (each segment has its own tensioner, and the length is limited so the tensioner range doesn't have to be huge). You need to pass power from one segment to another.

Comment: If droppers are there to balance the power between catenary and contact so why G JUMPERS are used on the overlap span as mentioned above, although C JUMPERS are there to transfer the power from catenary to catenary.

Comment: @Ankit because it's just as easy to tie all 4 wires than only two.  Two more clamps, a minute of your time.  And marginally better conductivity too.  Also the purpose of droppers is NOT to share power between catenary and contact.  The additional conductivity of the catenary wire is just a happy accident.

Comment: So in the case of voltage drop in the contact wire dropper will not pass the power through it?

Comment: @Ankit Current will follow all paths in proportion to their conductance.  So if you have a contact wire with 60 siemens (1/60 ohm) per kilometer conductance, and a catenary wire with 20 siemens (1/20 ohm) per kilometer.  Current will use both at 3:1 proportion.   By having that connector wire hit all 4, that means 1/4 of the current does not need to detour via the contact wire.